# Trying to get the largest result using nested IIF

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to get the largest result of 3 numbers using a nested IIF statement.  What I have so far but it keeps saying that it is expecting an end of statement. Thanks for the help!

```
IIF((IIF(Fields!Sold4Day.Value<Fields!Sold1Day.Value,Fields!Sold1Day.Value, Fields!Sold4Day.Value))<Fields!OnOrder1Day.Value,Fields!OnOrder1Day.Value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my mistake. Was missing the false part of the outer IIF

```
IIF((IIF(Fields!Sold4Day.Value<Fields!Sold1Day.Value, Fields!Sold1Day.Value, Fields!Sold4Day.Value))<Fields!OnOrder1Day.Value,Fields!OnOrder1Day.Value,(IIF(Fields!Sold4Day.Value<Fields!Sold1Day.Value, Fields!Sold1Day.Value, Fields!Sold4Day.Value)))
```